# Something like doxygen which can generate documentation for CSS?

Tags: linux, css, documentation-generator

Does anyone know any solution which can generate documentation based on comments in .css files, similarly to what is done for programming languages.

That is: If I have a list of .css files, then for each rule with a comment, it should extract the comment above the rule, as documentation for that rule.

Extra bonus if it can understand css selectors, so it knows how to group rules.

Example css

```
/** Use ButtonPanel for a div, which contains buttons */
.ButtonPanel { ... }

/** Set a button as right most, if it should align to the right, instead of the default left */
.ButtonPanel .rightMost { float:left; .... }
```

It would be really nice, if it know that .rightMost only could be used in side an ButtonPanel, so the documentation would reflect this with the description for ButtonPanel as the main description, and the documentation for .rightMost as documentation for things which can be placed inside that ButtonPanel.

Update:
And I need it to run on Linux. I use eclipse for development, but a free standing tool is fine.

Comment: On what OS should the tool run, and how much may it cost (if it comes to paid solutions)?

Comment: @Izzy I have updated with that information. Not sure about price: That depend on how good the tool is.